# How to redirect admin user on login page if user is not authorized or not logged in

Tags: laravel

I know this may be duplicate question but I am new to laravel and i am getting issue of `localhost redirected you too many times.` I want to do user should redirect on `admin/login` page in below scenario

1. if admin user is not logged in.
2. if the user is not admin and trying to access  then user should redirect to
   `http://localhost/blog/public/admin/login` this url

**In both cases system should redirect to admin/login page and ask for user to login** but my code is not working according to my expectation.

My web.php is

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['admin']],function(){    
    Route::get('/',"admin\AdminController@index");    
    Route::get('login',"admin\UserController@login");    
    Route::post("checkLogin","admin\UserController@checkLogin");
    Route::resource('products',"admin\ProductController");
    Route::resource('categories','admin\CategoryController');
    Route::resource('roles','admin\roleController');
    Route::resource('users','admin\UserController');

});
```

my admin middleware  is

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {   
        if(Auth::check() && (Auth::user()->user_type=="admin") ){
         return $next($request);
        }
           return redirect('admin/login');
    }
```

It shows me `This page isn’t working` what things i need to do in my middleware so that only admin user will get logged in .

Comment: It seems you have an evil `route` secretly defined somewhere and it is creeping into your carelessness :). Try doing `php artisan route:list` to see if you have any other redirects or conflicting routes set. I will advise you specifically check to confirm that there is no middleware set on that `admin/login` route

Comment: why have you added `Route::get('login',"admin\UserController@login");` inside `admin` middleware ? put it inside another route group that does not have admin middleware

Comment: GET|HEAD  | admin/login                      |                    | App\Http\Controllers\admin\UserController@login       | web,admin  this data i got

Comment: @rjk admin/login is for admin login it means only for admin authentication

Comment: but in admin middleware you are checking `auth` with 'admin` user_type, when it redirect to `admin/login` then again it check the middleware and so loop. just try to put it outside admin middleware

Comment: @vaibhavkulkarni does it work ?

Comment: @rkj can you please post your point as answer and let me know what things i need to change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174851/discussion-between-rkj-and-vaibhav-kulkarni).

Comment: @vaibhavkulkarni i have added answer check it

Answer (score 0):

Really need to see your controller code but this may be a good start.

Remove this:

```
Route::post("checkLogin","admin\UserController@checkLogin");
```

Change to:

```
Route::post("login","admin\UserController@checkLogin");
```

Because you should use the same login route name, one for post and one for get.

Handle Method

```
 public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
        {
            if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
                return redirect('/admin/login');
            }

            return $next($request);
        }
```

Comment: No its not working .Not logged in user can still access the http://localhost/blog/public/admin/products .So this should not happen,

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is easy to fix,

try to replace this line:

`return redirect('admin/login');`

to this line:

`return redirect('/admin/login');`

Answer (score 0):

In admin middleware you are checking auth with `admin` user_type, that means any unauthenticated request or none `admin` user_type get redirect to login route. However, your login route is also inside `admin` middleware so it get redirect loop. Your routes should be like this

Route without `admin` middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin'],function(){    
    Route::get('login',"admin\UserController@login");    
    Route::post("checkLogin","admin\UserController@checkLogin");
}
```

Route With `admin` middleware

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'admin','middleware'=>['admin']],function(){    
    Route::get('/',"admin\AdminController@index");    
    Route::resource('products',"admin\ProductController");
    Route::resource('categories','admin\CategoryController');
    Route::resource('roles','admin\roleController');
    Route::resource('users','admin\UserController');
});
```

You can use admin `namespace` in `Route::group` so that you don't have to add `admin\` in each controller name

Comment: it still goes to admin middleware after changing my route as per your solution as and face same problem.